# DB2: can't insert or select from temporary table

Tags: sql, db2

I have tried lots of permutations of `DECLARE` and `CREATE` but I can't display any data from my temporary table. Here's the latest iteration:

```
DECLARE GLOBAL TEMPORARY TABLE session.temporary_table (ACTNO CHAR); 
INSERT INTO session.temporary_table VALUES ('1'), ('2'); 
SELECT * FROM session.temporary_table; 
SELECT DISTINCT ACTKWD FROM JMILLER.ACT INNER JOIN session.temporary_table ON ACT.ACTNO = session.temporary_table.ACTNO; 
DROP TABLE session.temporary_table;
```

The first `SELECT` is to see if there's anything in the `temporary_table`. Which there doesn't seem to be.

[image]

Even though when I test the query in this tool it says every line of it completed correctly.

[image]

What am I doing wrong in my sql statements? I was having trouble with permissions earlier but that seems to be fine now and I'm not getting any errors, so it must be in my code.

Comment: See if this helps: https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/42226/db2-will-not-insert-into-created-temp-table-that-i-created/42228#42228

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You did not add the clause `ON COMMIT PRESERVE ROWS`.

Also see if you could make things simpler by using CTE (the `WITH` statement)

Comment: This isn't necessarily the only appropriate action; may be the OP does _not_ need to preserve rows on commit but rather disable the auto-commit function in the program.

Answer (score -1):

Modify to

```
 SELECT DISTINCT ACTKWD FROM JMILLER.ACT t0 INNER JOIN session.temporary_table t1 ON t0.ACTNO = t1.ACTNO;
```